# python ascii to unicode conversion

Tags: python, unicode

i have a file with data like this:

```
\r\n\tSoci\u00e9t\u00e9 implant\u00e9 dans l'internet recrute des t\u00e9l\u00e9conseillers en b to b pour effectuer de la prise de rendez-vous qualifi\u00e9 pour de la conception de site internet et du r\u00e9f\u00e9rencement google.
```

how can i print it as unicode, like this:

```
Société implanté dans l'internet recrute des téléconseillers en b to b pour effectuer de la prise de rendez-vous qualifié pour de la conception de site internet et du référencement google.
```

i know i have to use some unicode function but what?

Comment: Is this Python 2 or 3?

Comment: Where did this data come from? It could also be JSON (albeit malformed JSON unless there is more to this file than you posted here).

Comment: yes it's from a json file but my question was just how to print the original text from the first one

Comment: Then the `json` module will do the translation for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like a python unicode string literal; decode this from `unicode_escape`.

Demo:

```
>>> data = "\r\n\tSoci\u00e9t\u00e9 implant\u00e9 dans l'internet recrute des t\u00e9l\u00e9conseillers en b to b pour effectuer de la prise de rendez-vous qualifi\u00e9 pour de la conception de site internet et du r\u00e9f\u00e9rencement google."
>>> data.decode('unicode_escape')
u"\r\n\tSoci\xe9t\xe9 implant\xe9 dans l'internet recrute des t\xe9l\xe9conseillers en b to b pour effectuer de la prise de rendez-vous qualifi\xe9 pour de la conception de site internet et du r\xe9f\xe9rencement google."
>>> print data.decode('unicode_escape')

    Société implanté dans l'internet recrute des téléconseillers en b to b pour effectuer de la prise de rendez-vous qualifié pour de la conception de site internet et du référencement google.
```

You can either decode the data as you read it from the file (using a binary mode), or you can use `io.open()` in Python 2, or regular `open()` in Python 3 to have data decoded on the fly:

```
from io import open

with open(filename, 'r', encoding="unicode_escape") as inputfile:
    for line in inputfile:
        print(inputfile)
```

Note that JSON strings use the same escape syntax; `\uhhhh` denotes a Unicode codepoint using just ASCII characters.